# Table of Contents in a Journal

Tags: table-of-contents, fancyhdr, article, journal

I have a problem with the numbering of items.

I own the items separately and do not know how to put it together, for the numbering, etc, etc.

I have several articles, and need to get an index should be done as follows

```
                               Contents
```

Name of the Article

Author of Article .......................................................Page Number

Name of the Article

Author of Article .......................................................Page Number

Name of the Article

Author of Article .......................................................Page Number

Etc, etc.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Is the problem that you have several articles that are currently independent LaTeX files and you want to combine them into one document with a unified table of contents?

Comment: Yes, is exactly what I need, I have articles, generated separately, but do not know how to get a list of contents, or is there some way to get article in one file

Comment: hi all

I tested your recommendation, but I have a problem in the document to be combined figures exist, but I get this problem when there is no compilation and how to fix

the problem I get is:                                                            Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 72--73
[3] <oblique.pdf, id=20, 238.46692pt x 181.11665pt> <use oblique.pdf>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [combine class](http://ctan.org/pkg/combine). The combine class can be used to turn a collection of independent *.tex files into a compilation. Here is an example:

#### main.tex

```
\documentclass[book]{combine}
\title{A Book Example Using the Combine Class}
\author{TeX.SX}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
I'm adding an introduction to this collection

\begin{papers}
    \coltoctitle{Hello, World}
    \coltocauthor{Tom Thompson}
    \label{doc1}
    \import{doc1} % this is doc1.tex; notice the lack of *.tex in the file name

    \coltoctitle{Farewell, everyone}
    \coltocauthor{John Johnson}
    \label{doc2}
    \import{doc2}
\end{papers}

\chapter{Acknowledgements}
\emph{You}, for asking this question on TeX.SX!

\end{document}
```

#### doc1.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
Hello, world! How are you?

This is the end of the first part.
\end{document}
```

#### doc2.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Farewell}
Goodbye, World. I'll miss you.

This is the end of the second part.

\end{document}
```

Note that the `\import{}` command takes the name of the LaTeX file without the *.tex extension. See the [documentation for combine](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/combine/combine.pdf) for more information on how to use it.

Comment: I tested your recommendation, but I have a problem in the document to be combined figures exist, but I get this problem when there is no compilation and how to fix the problem I get is: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 72--73 [3] <oblique.pdf, id=20, 238.46692pt x 181.11665pt> <use oblique.pdf>